# control returns before calling delegate method of NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have to classes A and B . My B class having the method for connection with the server. I am calling this method from class A.I have implemented the delegate for NSURLConnection.class A having check connectivity function which is having the return type as a BOOL . I am invoking the ping method of class B from this method as follow:
class A:

```
-(BOOL)checkConnectivity:(Server *)newServer
{
    [b ping];
    return FALSE;
}
```

class B:

```
-(void)ping
{


    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"my url"];
    request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(connection)
    {
        webData=[NSMutableData data];
    }
}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}


-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Finished loading");   
}
```

there is no issue with the url. Then whats wrong?why delegate methods are not invoking ?

Comment: Have you checked to see if connection is not nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check u have added this:

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

Now do this in your ping method:

```
 NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                            initWithRequest:request
                                   delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] 
                  forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
 [connection start]
```

Comment: I'm sure this would work too, but it's not the answer to the op's problem.  I've copied and pasted his code, and it works fine.  Either there is something wrong with his URL, or the there's something else in his code he's not showing that's causing the problem.

Comment: No my url is working fine.Is there any problem because i am returning from checkConnection method?

Comment: @VXtreme, did you check to see if connection is non-nil like I asked in my comment?

Comment: Yes i have debugged the program connection is non nil.

Comment: @VXtreme, are any of the delegate methods being called?  Have you tried connection:didFailWithError: to see if it gets called?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15449/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-vxtreme)